# How to pass Annotation Type as a method parameter?

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop, aspect

There is a method that deals with Annotations something like

```
public void getAnnotationValue(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint)
{
     MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
     Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
     Annotation annotation = method.getParameterAnnotations()[0][0];
    RequestHeader requestParam = (RequestHeader) annotation;
    System.out.println(requestParam.value());
}
```

I want to convert it into a generic method that accepts joinPoint and Annotation Type something like

```
getAnnotationValue(joinPoint, RequestHeader);
```

For which I tried using:

```
public void getAnnotationValue(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType)
    {
         MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
         Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
         Annotation annotation = method.getParameterAnnotations()[0][0];
        annotationType requestParam = (annotationType) annotation;
        System.out.println(requestParam.value());
    }
```

But it prompts error stating `type unresolved error`? How to handle it and pass Annotation Value into that function!!

Comment: Unfortunately type is not a variable in java, you can use `Class` class though

Comment: @Andronicus I tried using Class<? extends Annotation> but it prompts the same error stating type unresolved

Comment: In that case please update your question to give a [mcve]. Plus: use the @user syntax when you want to ensure that other users are notified about comments you have for them.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" thing you could do:

```
public void foo(Class<? extends java.lang.annotation.Annotation> annotationClass) { ...
```

There is no specific "type" class for Annotations, but you fall back on ordinary Class objects, and simply express that you expect sub classes of the Annotation base class.

Comment: I have tried it but type unresolved error is getting prompted up!!

Comment: @KNDheeraj I figured that. Therefore I suggest you read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Give us a minimal example that shows that compiler error please. Otherwise we cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do just does not work that way. The problem is not the method signature but your wrong understanding of how to use types in Java. In this line ...

```java
annotationType requestParam = (annotationType) annotation;
```

... you have two errors:

- You cannot declare a variable with `annotationType requestParam` because `annotationType` is not a class name literal but a variable name. This is a syntax error and the compiler flags it as such.
- You cannot use `(annotationType) annotation` in order to cast for the same reason as in the first case. Java does not work that way, the code is just invalid.

Having said that, later on your code assumes that the captured annotation class has a method `value()`, which might happen to be true for some annotation classes, but would not work in a generic case. But assuming that method does exist in all cases in which you call the helper method, you could change it to read like this instead:

```java
public void getAnnotationValue(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
  MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
  Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
  Annotation annotation = method.getParameterAnnotations()[0][0];
  Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType = annotation.annotationType();
  try {
    System.out.println(annotationType.getMethod("value").invoke(annotation));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new SoftException(e);
  }
}
```

IMO this is very ugly and not good programming. But it compiles and runs. BTW, if the annotation type does not have a `value()` method, you will see a `NoSuchMethodException` thrown.

I think you are suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898) here. You are not describing which actual problem you want to solve but the way you believe the solution should look like, blinding yourself and others for better ways to solve the problem. Consequently, my sample code probably does not really solve your problem but just makes your ugly solution work somehow. This is not the same as good design.